# Dividing a set by a function's range? A complement of a function.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I want to read Carlitz paper on arithmetic functions and he defines a 'complement' of a function $f$ by $f'$. He defines it this way:

If $f$ is a function on the set $N$ of positive integers, $(f)$ is its range.

If $f$ is such a function that $N/(f)$ is inifinite, we define a strictly monotonic function $f'$ as follows:
$$(f')=N/(f)$$

So, what exactly does the $N/(f)$ mean here? Is it really division? If so, when is it and when is it not infinite?

Comment: I do not think so; maybe "setminus" ($\setminus$) i.e. [relative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)).

Answer (score 1):

It is not division...

It must be "setminus" ($\setminus$), i.e. [relative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)).

If so, we have a function $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ and let $(f)$ its [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics)).

Thus, we consider the set $\mathbb N \setminus (f)$.

*Silly example* : if $f$ is the constant function $1$, i.e. $f(n)=1$, for every $n$, we have that $(f)= \{ 1 \}$ and thus :

> $\mathbb N \setminus (f) = \mathbb N \setminus \{ 1 \} = \{ 2,3, \ldots \}$.

In this case we have that $\mathbb N \setminus (f)$ is infinite and we can indeed define a function $f'$ with : $(f') = \mathbb N \setminus (f)$ that is strictly monotonic (for example : $f'(n)=n+1$).

The key-point in the construction of $f'$ is that $\mathbb N \setminus (f)$ is infinite: otherwise, we have not enough values for $f'$ being strictly monotonic.

Comment: ok so the way I'm seeing this, this $f'$ must be strictly increasing to be specific?

Comment: @Satsuki - I think so... Consider the set $\mathbb N \setminus (f)$ in its natural order and let it $\{ a_1,a_2,\ldots \}$; we put $f'(1)=a_1, f'(2)=a_2, \ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not division-- that would make no sense.  In context I'm almost certain in "set minus" ans "complement"

$A \setminus B = \{a \in A$ so that $a \not \in B\}$.  In other words all the elements in $A$ that are not in $B$.

Let's work through an example.

Let $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ by $f(n)= n^2$.  (I'm not sure what will happen-- I'm reading your post as I type....)

"$(f)$ is the range"..... Okay that means $(f) = \{1,4,9,16,25,.....\}$.

$\mathbb N\setminus (f)$ is all the *other* natural numbers.  $\mathbb N\setminus (f) = \{2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,.....\}$.

"If f is such a function that N/(f) is inifinite"  In this case it is.

"we define a strictly monotonic function f′ as follows:
(f′)=N/(f)"

Okay.... so the range of $f'$ is $\{2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,.....\}$ and the function is monotonic so the is:

$f(1)\mapsto 2;f(2)\mapsto 3;f(3)\mapsto 5;f(4)\mapsto 6....$ etc.

The idea is that the for every function $f$ with a range with an infinite complement such a unique function can be defined.  Now it's hard to put it into a formula but such a function *does* exist and is well-defined.  I'd define it as:

$f(1) =2$

for any $n > 1$ if $f(n-1)$ is not a perfect square then $f(n) = f(n-1) + 1$.  BUt if $f(n-1)$ is a perfect square then $f(n) = f(n-1) + 2$.

This is the "complement" to $f(n) = n^2$.  It's a function that maps all the natural numbers to the numbers that $f$ does *not* map them to.

"when is it and when is it not infinite? "

A case without infinite would be, say $f(n) = n+ 4$.

$(f) = \{5,6,7,8,9,10,......\}$ and $\mathbb N\setminus (f) = \{n \in \mathbb N$ so that $n \not \in \{5,6,7,8,9,10,....\}\} = \{1,2,3,4\}$.  Which isn't infinite.

Your post doesn't tell use how to define $f'$ in this case (because we can't do a strictly monotonic function on a finite range.)

[If I had to guess he'd say to do a repeating function:  $f'(1)\mapsto 1;f'(2)\mapsto 2;f'(3)\mapsto 3;f'(4)\mapsto 4;f'(5)\mapsto 1;f'(6)\mapsto 2;f'(7)\mapsto 3;f'(8)\mapsto 4;f'(9)\mapsto 1;$ etc....  But I'm just second guessing Carlitz....  I could be wrong.]

[Or maybe he'd say do a monotonic function for the first $|\mathbb N\setminus(f)|$ values and then to a constant function from thereon out....]

[So $f'(1)=1; f(2) =2; f(3)=3; f(4)=4; f(n) =4$ if $n \ge 5$.]

[Or maybe Carlitz simply isn't defining a complementary function for a function with a finite complementary range...]

[But I'm second guessing him.]

Comment: Right.  So the question is how does Carlitz' define the "complimentary" function $f'(n)$ if the complement of the range is finite.  I'm second guessing him, but as the idea of a "compliment" function is one that maps to the complement of the range I'd figure he'd simply define it as a simple function that maps to a finite range.  I'm guessing $f(n) = n \% 4$ would be just fine.  Or maybe $f(n) = n$ for $n \le 4$ and $f(n) =4$ for $n> 4$.  But I'm second guessing Carlitz.